# I want to implement interface like "Google Duo" using Vertical Fragments in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-pageradapter

[image]

I want to Implement Interface in which the Screen is divided into two halves vertically and the lower half is partially visible, using Fragments just like in Google Duo application.
I am trying to achieve this thing using Fragment, some how I got succeeded to some extent but the problem is that fragments are not fluid in movement and the second fragment is not partially visible. Here is a piece of code

VertcialViewPager.Java

```
package com.example.deepdepindersingh.adore.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Deep Depinder Singh on 10/16/2016.
 */

public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {
    public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();

    }

    private void init() {
        // The majority of the magic happens here
        setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
        // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
        setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }
    private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                view.setAlpha(0);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
                    view.setAlpha(1);
                    // Counteract the default slide transition
                    view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

                    //set Y position to swipe in from top
                    float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
                    view.setTranslationY(yPosition);
            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
     */
    private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
        float width = getWidth();
        float height = getHeight();

        float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
        float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

        ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

        return ev;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
        swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
        return intercepted;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    }




    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        boolean wrapHeight = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec)
                == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;

        if(wrapHeight) {
            /**
             * The first super.onMeasure call made the pager take up all the
             * available height. Since we really wanted to wrap it, we need
             * to remeasure it. Luckily, after that call the first child is
             * now available. So, we take the height from it.
             */

            int width = getMeasuredWidth(), height = getMeasuredHeight();

            // Use the previously measured width but simplify the calculations
            widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

            /* If the pager actually has any children, take the first child's
             * height and call that our own */
            if(getChildCount() > 0) {
                View firstChild = getChildAt(0);

                /* The child was previously measured with exactly the full height.
                 * Allow it to wrap this time around. */
                firstChild.measure(widthMeasureSpec,
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));

                height = firstChild.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.deepdepindersingh.adore.ui.userinterface;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.example.deepdepindersingh.adore.ui.R;
import com.example.deepdepindersingh.adore.ui.userinterface.fragments.ListActivityFragment;
import com.example.deepdepindersingh.adore.ui.userinterface.fragments.MapActivityFragment;
import com.example.deepdepindersingh.adore.ui.userinterface.login.LoginActivity;
import com.example.deepdepindersingh.adore.ui.utils.Constants;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener{

    protected static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Intent intent = new  Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
       // startActivity(intent);



        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        VerticalViewPager viewPager = (VerticalViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        viewPager.setClipChildren(false);
        //viewPager.setPageMargin(getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.viewpager_margin));






        adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

}

    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }


        /**
         * Returns the proportional width of a given page as a percentage of the
         * ViewPager's measured width from (0.f-1.f]
         *
         * @param position The position of the page requested
         * @return Proportional width for the given page position
         */


        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                    return MapActivityFragment.newInstance(mPhoneNumber);
                case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                    return ListActivityFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }




        // Returns the page title for the top indicator
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }

    }
}
```

So please help me in creating this Interface which is fluid and similar to DUO application

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your desired behavior is, but it sounds like you could be using BottomSheets. These are introduced in design support library v23.2. [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) is a link to the Android dev blog about them.

Comment: I'm very certain it's a BottomSheet behavior.

Comment: thanx for the help